# How can I update a field starting with dollar in an embedded document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

I have a document in MongoDB in a collection with a document which has a field `x` which value is an embedded document, created this way:

```
> db.c.insert({_id: 1, x: {$a: 2, b: 3}})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.c.findOne({_id: 1})
{ "_id" : 1, "x" : { "$a" : 2, "b" : 3 } }
```

Note there is a field in the embedded document which starts with dollar (`$a`) and a field that doesn't start with dollar (`b`). I can update the field without dolar without problem:

```
> db.c.updateOne({_id: 1}, {$set: {"x.b": 30}})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
> db.c.findOne({_id: 1})
{ "_id" : 1, "x" : { "$a" : 2, "b" : 30 } }
```

However, if I try to update the field which starts with dollar in the same way, I get an error

```
> db.c.updateOne({_id: 1}, {$set: {"x.$a": 20}})
WriteError({
    "index" : 0,
    "code" : 52,
    "errmsg" : "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$a' in 'x.$a' is not valid for storage.",
    "op" : {
        "q" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "u" : {
            "$set" : {
                "x.$a" : 20
            }
        },
        "multi" : false,
        "upsert" : false
    }
})
```

Thus, how can I update a field starting with dollar in an embedded document?

I'm using MongoDB 4.4.1, in the case you need to know.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you change the field name? See [Restrictions on Field Names](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Restrictions-on-Field-Names): *the use of `$` and `.` in field names is not recommended and is not supported by the official MongoDB drivers.*

Comment: Does that recommendation refers to top-level fields or also sub-fields in embedded documents?

Comment: All fields. You are on your own when you use dots and dollars in any field name.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! So I understand that the update that I'm trying to do is not possible in MongoDB at the present moment, isn't it?

Comment: As far as I understand top-level field must not contain dollar `$`. In sub-fields it is permitted but not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to update field that start with `$`, see mongodb field name instructions,

**[Restrictions on Field Names](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Restrictions-on-Field-Names):**

- Field names cannot contain the null character.
- Top-level field names cannot start with the dollar sign ($) character.
  Otherwise, starting in MongoDB 3.6, the server permits storage of field names that contain dots (i.e. .) and dollar signs (i.e. $).

> **IMPORTANT**
>
> The MongoDB Query Language cannot always meaningfully express queries over documents whose field names contain these characters (see [SERVER-30575](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30575)).
>
> Until support is added in the query language, the use of $ and . in field names is not recommended and is not supported by the official MongoDB drivers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I understand by that note that fields starting with $ or . may have problems with queries. However, note that what I'm trying to do is an update operation (not a query).

Comment: However, note that `db.c.find({"x.$a": 2})` works and correctly returns the document...

Comment: You are right it should allow to update when its allowing in query part and also in insertion. i would suggest can you post a bug in [mongodb jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/samlsso?redirectTo=%2Fsecure%2FMyJiraHome.jspa), atleast we would get some update operation mechanism.

Comment: Good idea! Issue created at MongoDB JIRA: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-56462